# Perl eBay::API passing a listing title to get the category

Tags: perl, categories, ebay-api

I'm wondering if, using Perl's [eBay::API](http://www.metacpan.org/module/eBay%3a%3aAPI), there is a way to pass the title of a potential listing and return a category recommendation?

For example, if I entered "Lapierre Zesty 914 2013" it would return something like
"Sporting Goods > Cycling > Bikes" or perhaps a set of possibilities?

I started looking at http://search.cpan.org/~tkeefer/eBay-API-0.25/, but there are so many modules, I hoped someone could point me at the right one...

I'm searching eBay.co.uk. If [eBay::API](http://www.metacpan.org/module/eBay%3a%3aAPI) doens't do it, but something else does (in Perl), please do say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, two minutes after asking, I found it: `GetSuggestedCategories` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

On http://search.cpan.org/~tkeefer/eBay-API-0.25/, find the "Other tools" link. There's a search function so you can find things in all of the distribution files. Looking for keywords such as "suggested" often lead you in the right direction. :)

[image: Other tools link on distribution summary page]